# Rad Mask TextBox: Change Text to upper and position cursor at end of the text.

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, telerik, radmaskedtextbox

I have Rad Mask TextBox and a button. So user can enter any case into the text box. when button is clicked,  I am fetching some record based on text and event I have to change the text to upper, trim and position the caret to end.

I noticed, if upper case is entered, I get all the scenario's but when lower case is entered the postion of cursor is pointed to beginning.

this is what I tried.

```
        txtSearch.MaskedText = txtSearch.MaskedText.ToUpperInvariant().Trim();
        txtSearch.SelectionOnFocus = SelectionOnFocus.CaretToEnd;
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectionStart has solved the requirement.

```
         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (txtSearch.MaskedText != null)
            {
                txtSearch.MaskedText = txtSearch.MaskedText.ToUpper();
                txtSearch.SelectionStart = txtSearch.MaskedText.Length;
                txtSearch.Focus();
            }
        });
```