# MaskedTextBox Enforce UpperCase Characters

Tags: c#, mvvm, telerik

I'm utilizing Telerik's RadMaskedTextBox and I'm trying to create a Mask such that it'll follow Canadian Postal Code template.

Template is as followed Letter Number Letter Number Letter Number

Example postal code `T4R1U8`

At the moment my Mask is `Mask="L#L #L#"` but this allows both uppercase and lowercase letters. I'm trying to have it so that Uppercase letters can be inputted AND lower case can be inputted but the lower case will immediately change to upper.

I've tried two solutions, they are very close but not quite the final solution.

First one is tackling this on the viewmodel side

```
public string PostalCode
{
    get {return postalCode;}
    set
    {
        postalCode = value;
        postalCode = postalCode.ToUpper();
        OnPropertyChanged("PostalCode");
    }
}
```

This approach,  the values will change to upper but the typing index moves to the front of the MaskTextBox instead of always remaining after character that is typed.

The Second approach I took works well but doesn't allow me to type lowercase characters. I ended Up using a CustomToken. '*' is my custom token char so my new mask is `Mask="*#* #*#"`

```
public class CustomToken : ITokenValidationRule
{
    #region ITokenValidationRule Members

    public bool IsRequired
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool IsValid(char ch)
    {
        return ValidChars.Contains(ch);
    }

    public char Token
    {
        get { return '*'; }
    }

    public TokenTypes Type
    {
        get { return TokenTypes.AlphaNumeric; }
    }

    private string myValidChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public string ValidChars
    {
        get { return myValidChars; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version? WPF, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817987/rad-mask-textbox-change-text-to-upper-and-position-cursor-at-end-of-the-text).

The solution is to use the SelectionStart to set the Caret at the end, eg:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    if (txtPOCode.MaskedText != null)
    {
        txtPOCode.MaskedText = txtPOCode.MaskedText.ToUpper();
        txtPOCode.SelectionStart = txtPOCode.MaskedText.Length;
        txtPOCode.Focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that this breaks down a bit if the user inserts text in the middle (as it will force the text to be at the end).  I would think you'd want to save the selection position, convert to uppercase, then restore.

Answer (score 1):

To enforce uppercase characters in a MaskedTextBox control, add a ">" character to the start of your mask string.

Example: For a CD Key entry mask where the CD Key will have 5 groups of 4 letters/numbers separated by dashes and you want it all upper case, then set the mask to:
">AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA".

The leading ">" won't appear in the placeholder text in the MaskedTextBox at runtime.

The textbox will show only underscores and dashes like this:
[____ - ____ - ____ - ____ - ____]

All characters entered will be converted to upper case and it will only allow letters/numbers in the entry.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your wanting to accomplish here.

If you want to what is keyed in as upper case on the letters, then have you tried setting the font to charactercasing

TextBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;

Or set it on the properties on the form, as it may be required to place behind a key press event.

Or Set it in the Element to "Upper" in xaml

```
<TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValueConverter or MarkupConverter.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(IValueConverter))]
public class ToUpperConverter : MarkupConverter
{
    private static ToUpperConverter _instance;

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static ToUpperConverter()
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return _instance ?? (_instance = new ToUpperConverter());
    }

    protected override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = value as string;
        return val != null ? val.ToUpper() : value;
    }

    protected override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the Telerik RadMaskedTextInput control, there is a limitation for the formatting tokens so you need to declare the mask using the numeric syntax rather than the literal syntax. For example, the mask "LLL" should be used like "L3" when using the formatting token. In your case you'll be using L1 and d1 tokens, and whether you're using WinForms or WPF (you didn't specify which) the mask for postal code should be:

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextInput Mask="&gt;L1d1&gt;L1 d1&gt;L1d1"/>
```

The ">" casing character performs the conversion to upper case.